# Update in android

Tags: android, database

I am updating table in database using the following command:

```
public long UpdateIncomeDB(String item,String price,String update) throws SQLException
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESC, item);
    initialValues.put(KEY_INCOME, price);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TOTAL, price);
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, initialValues, "description" + "=" +update, null);
    return 0;
}
```

But is showing error that the particular column doesn't exists..But i checked database which has that column entry..Please help me..

MY logcat is:

```
07-20 11:25:03.157: E/Database(1090): Error updating total=45.00 price=45.00 description=ghhy using UPDATE incomexpense SET total=?, price=?, description=? WHERE description=ghhy
07-20 11:25:03.167: D/AndroidRuntime(1090): Shutting down VM
07-20 11:25:03.167: W/dalvikvm(1090): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-20 11:25:03.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-20 11:25:03.617: D/dalvikvm(1090): GC freed 7418 objects / 376640 bytes in 421ms
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ghhy: , while compiling: UPDATE incomexpense SET total=?, price=?, description=? WHERE description=ghhy
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1027)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1556)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1500)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.budget1.DBadapter.UpdateIncomeDB(DBadapter.java:575)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.budget1.IncomeDetailsEdit$2.onClick(IncomeDetailsEdit.java:46)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-20 11:25:03.617: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put update value inside quotes

```
"description" + "=" +update
```

Put quotes

```
"description" + "=" +"'"+update+"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this where clause:   "description='" +update + "'"

All String values in SQL queries should be rounded by '